# ZFS send/receive over ssh on linux without allowing root login

Tags: linux, ssh, sudo, zfs

I wish to replicate the file system `storage/photos` from `source` to `destination` without enabling ssh login as root. I've tried a number of different combinations such as:

```
sudo zfs send -R storage/photos@frequent_2015-02-12_18:15 | ssh example.com sudo zfs recieve storage/photos
sudo zfs send -R storage/photos@frequent_2015-02-12_18:15 | ssh example.com su -c zfs recieve storage/photos
sudo zfs send -R storage/photos@frequent_2015-02-12_18:15 | ssh example.com 'sudo -S zfs recieve storage/photos <~/topsecret'
```

I can't use sudo -S to pass the password as the zfs stream is already hooked up to the standard input. And the two examples above that expects an interactive terminal and not stdin.

Perhaps it's silly not to want to enable root login on a server. But it leaves one more thing for a brute force attacker to guess which is nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't completely remove root login, but it does secure things beyond a full-featured login.

Set up an SSH trust by copying the local user's public key (usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) to the authorized_keys file (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) for the remote user. This eliminates password prompts, and improves security as SSH keys are harder to bruteforce. You probably also want to make sure that `sshd_config` has `PermitRootLogin without-password` -- this restricts remote root logins to SSH keys only (even the correct password will fail).

You can then add security by using the `ForceCommand` directive in the authorized_keys file to permit only the zfs command to be executed.

Answer (score 12):

I came upon the same problem earlier today. I found that you can authorize regular users to do certain operations with the "zfs allow" command:

as root, do the following on the server:
zfs allow your_username receive,create,mount storage/photos

Afterwards, you'll be able to ssh into the server using your_username and you'll have zfs privileges to receive.
See here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gfkco/index.html

Comment: On Ubuntu Xenial, after running `sudo zfs allow myuser receive,create,mount tank/test2`, I still cannot perform `sudo zfs send -i snap1 tank/test@snap2 | zfs recv tank/test2` due to the `Permission denied the ZFS utilities must be run as root.` error. It seems [ZoL still doesn't support `zfs allow`](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/434).

Comment: [`zfs allow` support was just added to zfsonlinux](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/commit/f74b821a6696fef9e9953aae05941e99bf83800e) (some limitations remain, see the commit message)

Answer (score 8):

@analog900 is on the right track.

One key to increased security, including avoiding the need for root logins, is to use the built-in permissions structure of ZFS, and also to structure your backup transfers the other way 'round and **pull** your backups over the network, rather than pushing them.  The ability to back up filesystems without root access is one of the major design achievements of the ZFS filesystem.

Run the job on `destination` and pull the data from `source`, perhaps something like:

- On the **source** machine, create a non-privileged user account `foo` and use `zfs allow` to give that account the ability to create and send snapshots:

```
    zfs allow foo mount,snapshot,send,hold storage/photos
```

- On the **destination** machine, create a non-privileged account `bar` and give that account the ability to receive/create/mount filesystems:

```
    zfs allow bar mount,create,receive storage/photos
```

- On destination, as user `bar`, create an ssh key specifically for backup jobs.  Install the public half of that key in the `.ssh` directory of user `foo` on the source machine.  This gives user `bar@destination` secure ssh login access to the `foo@source` account.  Also, edit the ~bar/.ssh/config file on `destination` so that it automatically uses the correct SSH key filename (which you created earlier) and username:

```
    Host source
       Hostname FQDN.of.source.example.com
       User foo
       IdentityFile ~bar/.ssh/backup_key_id_rsa
```

- Now run your backup job from `bar@destination`:

```
    dt=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S)
    ssh source "zfs snap storage/photos@frequent_$dt"
    ssh source "zfs send -R storage/photos@frequent_$dt" | zfs receive storage/photos
```

Doing it this way requires **no** root access whatsoever.

Comment: This almost worked for me BUT for some reason also needed the `hold` permission on the sender side. I was sending an encryped dataset via `pyznap`, but I am not sure why that lead to me needing the `hold` permission.

Comment: Thank you, @mschwaig, you're correct.  I checked one of my installations and that permission is present.  I've edited the answer to include your comment.

Comment: It's a shame it's [not possible to allow only raw sends yet](https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/13099). If the backup machine is not trusted with sensitive data, push is currently the only way.

Answer (score 3):

For those who haven't been upgraded to 0.7.0 yet, here's a solution I came up with. SSH into the remote server and run:

```
mkfifo zfs-pipe

# It doesn't ask for your password until the pipe starts to receive 
# data. So check back here when you start the local command
sudo zfs receive storage/photos < zfs-pipe
```

Then locally:

```
sudo zfs send -R storage/photos@frequent_2015-02-12_18:15 | \
       pv | ssh example.com "cat - > zfs-pipe"
```

`pv` is optional of course. It's just nice to have something to watch for progress

Lastly clean up the pipe:

```
rm zfs-pipe
```

Comment: Lovely solution! Of course, facilities such as `zfs allow` or passwordless `sudo` are the 'proper' way to do this now, but this answer deserves +1s for demonstrating just how elegant and powerful GNU/Linux' "pipes and filters" architecture is.

Answer (score 2):

2022 most use mbuffer on FreeBSD. I wouldn't take advice from people saying use ssh to login to other hosts to do backups, bad idea. Use mbuffer over wireguard. Permitrootlogin always to no, no exceptions. If your using ssh to do backups, packets will fragment leading to inefficiencies on speed + the overhead of encrypting across the line with a lot of lost CPU cycles. Imagine going over VPN, then encrypting again with SSH, makes no sense. And on local LAN you definitely don't care about encrypting across the line to begin with, you just want speed, you can always setup a VLAN for that if your paranoid.

Whatever port you use on the machine for it, firewall port off to all except the backup host. Reason people use mbuffer is because you can specify blocksize to matchup with recordsize of your pool so your backups are very fast.

At end of day your backup should consist of a simple cronjob line connecting to the host, don't over complicate ever beyond this, if you have to, write a shell script and still keep it as a 1 liner.

If your more advanced just code your own socket daemon to accept requests with epoll on linux or kqueue on FreeBSD, that way you can administrate all your machines with any command you choose.

Very simple example of cronjob to create daily snapshots and monthly on FreeBSD:

```
0 3 * * * (zfs destroy data@`/bin/date +\%A`;zfs snapshot data@`/bin/date +\%A`)              > /dev/null 2>&1
0 3 1 * * (zfs destroy data@`/bin/date +\%B`;zfs snapshot data@`/bin/date +\%B`)              > /dev/null 2>&1
```

add another line to use mbuffer to replicate data with your daily snapshot, very simple. Alternatively you could use a third party package to do it all for you, good luck with debugging someone else's program when something breaks down or they decide to stop supporting it, keep it simple.

Here are some 1 liners for mbuffer:
https://www.mceith.com/blog/?p=183

If your a system admin, I wouldn't even bother running ZFS on anything but FreeBSD, unless you like fighting with kernel versions all the time to get support on Linux. It is very simple to use a Linux KVM host up front and passthrough ZFS or PCIE device drives to FreeBSD, I wouldn't allow main host to do anything but virtualization, routing, vpn and firewall. Stick Rocky Linux on it, and change kernel to kernel-ml, about it, keep it rock solid for your guests. At very minimum 5.15.x kernel series if you want to run wireguard.

I have great speeds at home running ZFS samba off my 10 gigabit LAN to VLC player on google tv chromecast, I have had rock solid performance on FreeBSD on remote servers using wireguard to backup the hosts offsite. My preference for backups is like a mirror but using 2 separate machines always, if 1 machine ever fails, you still have a working machine to use till other one gets fixed. (I can't count how many mechanical drives have failed anymore, they are a sys admin nightmare)

For a decades I have never had a problem doing this, but second I start importing pools into Linux I have corrupted them and had to restore off backups, not worth your time. I can update between revisions on FreeBSD on the fly with no downtime. On Linux you'd have to reformat half the time between RHEL revisions, keep your data safe on FreeBSD.

Over years I have seen people do some of dumbest backups, copying entire KVM guests as backups, for linux all you need is /etc, home directory and database directories. FreeBSD same thing, but /usr/local/etc as well. Keep it simple, want to use SSDs right?

Hopefully one day we can get rid of mechanical spinning rust bucket drives, and let people have 20TB SSD's for $100, greedy SSD manufacturers are holding people back.